# BreezeJS "group by" method

Tags: javascript, breeze

Is there some way to group entities downloaded from service in BreezeJS ?

I had found things like "where" "select" "orderBy" but i'm missing "groupBy" method

Do you know if exists ? or if there is other way to do this ?

Answer (score 3):

"GroupBy" is not part of the OData query standard and is not an operation supported by Breeze.

I can imagine utility to this operation ... returning a data structure representing the Groups and populated with entities. If the grouping is predictable, you could create a controller endpoint to perform the group by for you and send that grouped data to the client. Breeze will harvest the entities buried within the data structure and your query result will reflect the grouping effort that you delegated to the server.

Comment: Yes, this is actually the solution that i have applied. But i was thinking this was included on breeze core.

Comment: It isn't in part because it isn't part of the OData spec and there is no URL syntax for it. I note also that, in LINQ, the GroupBy can appear in a number of other places of a complex query where the semantics are much more difficult to apply and it's not clear (to me anyway) how one could express the request in an extended OData query string. Too many uncertainties for us at this time.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean exactly by "group by"? 
Maybe Breeze does allow something like that, but not that I know of.

Since the point of Breeze is to send results that are observables, a group by in the SQL sense, well does not make a lot of sense. You would have to do it yourself. For example, how can a count(*) be an observable?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion a `GroupBy` OData in a general sense has little interest. It can easily be implemented using the `OrderBy` operator.

The real interest of `GroupBy` is to perform **aggregation**. **And this server side**.

I have long pondered the question. I developed the product AdaptiveLINQ ([www.adaptivelinq.com](http://www.adaptivelinq.com)) which through its (server side: for .Net developer) extension method `QueryByCube` allows an aggregation specifying a simple `Select` directive.

Thus one can easily build a service that, for example, returns the total sales per customer:

```
http://.../MyAnalysisService.svc/Sales?$select=Customer, Sales
```

or per customer and product category

```
http://.../MyAnalysisService.svc/Sales?$select=Customer, ProductCategory, Sales
```